# VB.NET code need solution

Tags: .net, vb.net

**I want to put all caracters (ALL!) Example : ✭&4kasdf'224584m~™¶Ы∆█א〤龍龙Ѣ෴ℲɣɆ铑稥ẁ⒈ﷴﻦﻫŹÉЏ
in a BD... for dat i use UTF-8 in my table look:**

```
CREATE TABLE `clan` (
  `IdClan` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdClan`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But when i want to make this ask whit my program dont works... the program dont compar

**Form1:**

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim unGuildenIdent As New clsGuildenIdent
    Dim unClan As New clsClan
    unClan.IdClan = txttag.Text
    unClan = unGuildenIdent.darUnClan(txttag.Text)


End Sub
```

**ClsClan**

```
Public Class clsClan
    Private mIdClan As String
    Public Property IdClan() As String
        Get
            Return mIdClan
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mIdClan = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function darUnClan(ByVal IdClan As String) As clsClan
        Dim unClan As New clsPClan
        Return unClan.darUnClan(IdClan)
    End Function
End Class
```

**clsPClan**

```
Public Function darUnClan(ByVal IdClan As String) As clsClan
    Dim unClan As New clsClan
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT Premium FROM clan WHERE IdClan='" & IdClan & "'"
    Dim resultados = ejecutarYdevolver(sql)
    If resultados.HasRows Then
        resultados.Read()
        unClan = crearClan(resultados)
    End If
    Return unClan
End Function
```

When i send ✭ this caracter they dont give me the Premium but this caracter exist in de BD... what i have wrong?

Thnx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you create the table, change 'IDClan' to be NVarChar instead of VarChar

Comment: This is what you say? o.O

``CREATE TABLE `clan` (
  `IdClan` NVarChar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdClan`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;``